# ClassNotFoundException when creating a new package

Tags: java, servlets, gwt

I have a project made in gwt. Now I'm trying to create a servlet that automatically triggers some functions.
So I create a new package in my application, and inside that, a new class containing the servlet.

In this way I have three packages in my applcation: one that contains server functions, one that contains client functions e one that contains the servlet.
The problem is that when I start my application I get the ClassNotFoundException package-that-contains-servlet.

It's like the application does not see at all the new package I added.
How can I solve this?

Comment: do you have an web.xml file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need to add a web.xml file to your project. If you are using netbeans go to new file--web--standard deployment descriptor(web.xml).
Then you must add the servlet information to the web.xml file.
This will tell the application where to look for the class.

Here is an exmaple of servlet config in a web.xml file.

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>mypackage.MyServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/MyServlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: That's the correct answer! I forgot the whole servlet-mapping part!

Comment: Yeah I understand. I was studying this in college and the course notes didn't mention anything about the web.xml. I know how frustrating that can be.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to map the servlet. Check ur web.xml file..

```
   <servlet>
     <servlet-name>ServletName</servlet-name>
     <servlet-class>YourPackage</servlet-class>
   </servlet>

   <servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>ServletName</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/projectName/your RemoteServiceRelativePath()</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
```

Change the above line according to ur class specification and add to web.xml